# Comparison between the first columns of 2 different files with awk

Tags: bash, awk

I would like to add in my script a comparison between the first columns of 2 different files. When an element of the first file (1st column) is the same with an element of the second file (first column), then I want to write to a new file the elements that are previous to the same elements of the second file. In this example the years `1789` and `2007` should be in the output.

1st file

```
1860
1934
1960
2001
2011
```

2nd file

```
1789
1934
1980
2007
2011
```

I tried this without success:

```
cat File1.dat File2.dat | awk '{$1=a[$1]; next} {print a[$1]-1}' > Output.dat
```

Comment: That's not quite the pattern for that. You need to hand awk both the files directly (not through `cat`/a pipe) and you need to guard the first action block with `NR==FNR` to have it only run for the first file (when the absolute row number processed (`NR`) is equivalent to the row number in the current file `FNR`).

Comment: What (and how much) of the contents from the first file do you want written out when the contents of the second file match? What should the output file for those two input files be exactly?

Comment: The output should be 1789 and 2007. I want the previous element of the matching elements of the 2nd file.

Comment: +1 because you actually posted some of your attempts. To compare two fields we normally use the trick `awk 'FNR==NR {process_info_in_first_file; next} {process_info_in_second_file}' file1 file2`. See http://backreference.org/2010/02/10/idiomatic-awk/ for more info.

Comment: Etan Reisner, if I understood correctly what NR and NFR are, I didn't use them because my files have different number of lines. Regarding the handling of files directly, I have no idea how to do it (I have just started to learn programming, scripting etc). But thanks anyway :-)

Comment: Thanks a lot fedorqui, I will try again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `awk`:

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{a[FNR]=$1; next}$1==a[FNR]{print a[FNR-1]}' file2 file1
1789
2007
```

Using `NR==FNR` construct, we store lines of file2 in an array. Once the file2 has been stored in memory, we move to iterate file1. When the line from file1 matches to the corresponding line of file2, we print the previous line from our array.

Answer (score 2):

```
kent$  paste f1 f2|awk '$1==$2{print p}{p=$2}'
1789
2007
```

Comment: It doesn't work, it says I don't have access permissions to the file.